# char c1[ ]="abcde" works while char *c1="abcde" turns out wrong?

Tags: c

I was working on the "c programming language" exercise2.4, which deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2.Below is my code, it works. However,if I change the definition in Main function from `char c1[ ]="abcde"` to `char *c1="abcde"`, it will turns out segmentation fault(core dumped). Any idea why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define UNREPEAT 1
#define REPEAT 0

void squeeze(char *s1,char *s2);

void main(){
char c1[]="abcde";
char c2[]="cd";
printf("c1 is %s\n",c1);
squeeze(c1,c2);
printf("the final result is %s\n",c1);
}

void squeeze(char *s1,char *s2){
int i,j,judge;
int k=0;
for(i=0;*(s1+i)!='\0';i++){
  judge=UNREPEAT;   
   for(j=0;*(s2+j)!='\0';j++){
     if (*(s1+i)==*(s2+j)){
      judge=REPEAT;
      break;}
    }

if( judge==UNREPEAT){
  * (s1+k)=*(s1+i);
  k++;}

 }
 *(s1+k)='\0'; 
 }
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Yeah `* (s1+k)=*(s1+i);` is having problem...

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
char c1[] = "abcde";
```

declares an array, it's readable and writable and will always have 6 bytes (if you consider the terminating `'\0'`) you can't extend it but of course you can use it to store less bytes.

While

```
char *c1 = "abcde";
```

is a static string literal it shall not be modified, you should always declare string literals using the `const` qualifier, that way the compiler would warn you if you try to modify its contents, which is illegal, just use

```
const char *c1 = "abcde";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *c1="abcde"
```

This is a string literal which is read-only and in your function you try to change the contents of it so you might hit seg fault.

Whereas the other case

```
char c1[] = "abcde";
```

You are allocating memory on the stack whose contents can be modified.

PS: String literals are read-only